# How to use require() in Reactjs with .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, requirejs, browserify

Hi I've been working with Reactjs inside a .net mvc project for a few days but I haven't use require function in my react components. Because react core files are imported in html before my components. So I just write React.createClass to create a new components. But I started to think what happen in production. Because I'll use .min.js files and probably React will be undefined.

Now, I'm trying to use require function to use react and other components. But I'm confused to use require(). Should I use requirejs or browserify? Also I couldn't find a good article to use these libraries with mvc.net.

Comment: It is preferable to use ES 2015, now that it is a standard. import is better than require. In the component file, use the class style of defining component - export default class MyComp extends React.Component {}

Comment: Thanks Vijay. But I looked ecmaScript and I think that If  I want to use ecmaScript with jsx and I need gulp. Is there any way to use ecmaScript with jsx without gulp?

Comment: I decided to use Asp.net Core. Beucase it has npm and I configured webpack easily.